# how to call rest api from other web project

Tags: javascript, java

I created two projects:

1. web project having all client-side code.
2. project have server-side code like rest API etc..

Using tomcat server when I tried to call rest API from web project it can't access API. How can access rest API from other projects?

gives Error: **HTTP Status 404 - /clientSide/rest/hello**

1. client side code

   `<a href="/rest/hello">Click Here</a>`
2. server side code

Hello.java

```
@Path("/hello")

public class Hello {
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey Plain";
  }
  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey HTML" + "</h1></body>" + "</html> ";
  }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>flatMateWeb</display-name>
   <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
        <param-value>com.javatpoint.rest</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

Comment: If you make request using javascript you need to implement CORS at API end point

Comment: What technology stack do you use on client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you are making is that you are not specifying full path of your resource which is `IpAddress:port/War-name/url-pattern/resource-name` but your resource path is`/clientSide/rest/hello`.

For example I created a Rest API and built a war names `War_name` and deployed it on `tomcat` running `locally` on port `8080`. Now I created a client-side code as shown below. Pay attention to the `href` part.

```
<html>

    <body>

        <h1>Test</h1>

        <a href="http://localhost:8080/War_Name/rest/names">Link</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

You can see how I have mentioned the `full-path to the resource` - **http://localhost:8080/War_Name/rest/names**. After specifying the IpAddress and port I have war_name then the `url-pattern` and finally path to the resource specified in `@Path` annotation.

When I click on the `Link` I am able to see the output returned by my Rest-Api.